# dosemu crashes under LTS 12.04

Tags: 12.04, dosbox

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS from 10.04.  A DOS application that previously ran under dosemu now crashes with only the message "[4] Exit 194" displayed in the window from which I started it.

Any suggestions on how I should debug this problem?  Has there been a change to dosemu for 12.04?  Should I re-install dosemu?

Comment: Which application? Have you tried it in dosbox instead? Has the error message affecting the application been reported as a bug [on the tracker](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/bugtrackers/sf)? or [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/dosemu/bugs/)?

Comment: I should also reinstall and check your configuration files such as `~/.dosemurc`. Without more information the question is unanswerable. Also check the release notes for the 12.04 version to check if anything changed with regard to application compatibility within `dosemu`.